# Electron : Wrote new app to release-builds : Is this successful ? What happens next?

Tags: javascript, json, linux, electron

I apologize for my ignorance, but not sure how I execute my packaged project.

Here is outcome:

```
harry@debian:/usr/lib/node_modules$ electron-packager --electron-version=1.7.9 . /home/harry/sound/SickBayScanner --overwrite  --platform=linux --arch=x64 --DEBUG=* --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

Packaging app for platform linux x64 using electron v1.7.9

Wrote new app to `release-builds/-home-harry-sound-SickBayScanner-linux-x64`

How do you execute the build ?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the `release-builds/-home-harry-sound-SickBayScanner-linux-x64` folder you will see lots of files one of which is an executable that you can run.

It's annoying to have to give the whole folder to everyone who uses it but I haven't found a good way to compress it into one file, I've tried things like [electron-installer-debian](https://github.com/unindented/electron-installer-debian) and it would generate a .deb file but it wouldn't install.

Comment: There is an executable in there.  Do I execute it by typing ./executable ?  How do you execute it from the command like.  Tried clicking on it and nothing.